# Override response of POST in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I'm using Django Rest Framework's Generics (generics.ListCreateAPIView), when I make a POST request I get a response of Http code (200/400/..etc.) and a JSON showing the posted data, I need to know how can I override the response to get a custom response.

Note that I use

```
    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        return Response(<my response>)
```

to override the POST request handling but I still get the same response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response from `perform_create` is ignored.
You'll likely want to override the `create` method using the [mixins](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L18-L23) as example

Comment: Should I use Mixins instead of generics, or is there a way to use both together ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but the idea is that you copy/paste the linked create method in your code, use the serializer.data as a base to build your own response data and finally pass them to the response. If you need to make that to several views you should definitively consider a Mixin that you'll add to your views.

Comment: Working, Thank you!

Comment: The problem with this is that if you override create instead of perform_create you need to (usually) copy a lot of the code in the normal create() in DRF. As DRF evolves, this might change and every piece of code you had to take from DRF into your overrides will eventually rot unless maintained. While you can't return custom responses directly from perform_create, you can derive your own APIExceptions and raise them there, and let the default APIView relay their custom contents to the client.

Comment: "As DRF evolves, this might change" quite unlikely. Python 2 migration appart, most of the code is 6 years old and some part have been optimised 4 years ago (though you'll optimise better by yourself anyway). That's stable enough.